# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "solidus_i18n":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

I am trying to install solidus_globalize but I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "solidus_i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    solidus_i18n

solidus_globalize was resolved to 3.1.0.beta, which depends on
  solidus_i18n (~> 1.0)
```

In gemfile:

```
gem 'globalize', github: 'globalize/globalize'
gem 'solidus_i18n', github: 'solidusio-contrib/solidus_i18n'
gem 'solidus_globalize', github: 'solidusio-contrib/solidus_globalize'
```

Comment: Are you sure you need explicit `github` keys? What if you remove it for only `solidus_i18n` gem. And also if you remove it from all 3?

Comment: I remove it and i got the same resault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem 'globalize'
gem 'solidus_i18n'
gem 'solidus_globalize', github: 'solidusio-contrib/solidus_globalize'
```

Worked for me on rails 5.